# Mod rewrite regex without specific url sequence

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL structure like this

```
mydomain.com/category/--_brand/---color.html
```

So the brands always begins with a `--_` and the color always with `---`. However the order and amout of the URL parts can change, e.g.:

```
mydomain.com/category/---color.html    or
mydomain.com/category/---color/--_brand.html
```

The result of the RewriteRule should be somehting like this:

```
index.php?category=$1&color=$2&brand=$3
```

At the moment, all I have is this in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)\.html$ index.php?category=$1&color=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So it's only for the category and color and it doesn't check whether color begins with '---' or not, which would be a problem if the order of the URL parts change.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The following rule would take care of `/category/--_brand/---color.html` and the `/category/---color.html` URLs i.e when the brand appears optionally.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(?:--_([^/]+)/)?---(.*)\.html$ index.php?category=$1&brand=$2&color=$3 [L,QSA]
```

You would need another rule for `/category/---color/--_brand.html` i.e when the order in which color and brand appears changes.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/---([^/]+)/--_(.*)\.html$ index.php?category=$1&color=$2&brand=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Good answer +1, it should work but very strange requirements I must say.